# Setting up flask csrf protection and stripe

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, stripe-payments, csrf

I'm following [this](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart) tutorial from stripe documentation to integrate stripe with flask, but there's some simplicity when it comes to security probably because it's a quickstart.

This following code creates the checkout, and after the user subscribes, the user goes directly to the `/success.html` and here goes also the `CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID` which is also the customer id, as you can see below.

`checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(line_items=[{'price': prices.data[0].id,'quantity': 1,},],mode='subscription',success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN +'/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/cancel.html',)`

After that, there is a script inside this article called `client.js`, with this code:

```
// In production, this should check CSRF, and not pass the session ID. 
// The customer ID for the portal should be pulled from the 
// authenticated user on the server. 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);     
    if (searchParams.has('session_id')) {
        const session_id = searchParams.get('session_id');         
        document.getElementById('session-id').setAttribute('value', session_id);
} });
```

This code, captures the `CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID` (also customer id) from `/success.html?session_id=CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID` so the billing portal can be created.

My question is related to the JS comment, I don't really understand how to pass the csrf instead of the session ID. I already pull the customer ID from the server, but now what should I pass instead? the csrf token? isn´t that supposed to be secret?

Hope anyone can help me. If I missed something please let me know so I can add it up.

I integrated the `CSRFProtect` library and initiated it with `csrf = CSRFProtect() csrf.init_app(app)`

I add the `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` element inside my forms. Then I pulled out the `{{ csrf_token() }}` when the form got submitted. I store it to pass this token in the `/success.html?session_id=` instead of the customer id, like this `/success.html?session_id={csrf_token}`. But I know something is wrong.